Grid layout but with rows of auto height
I have a code like this:
  <div className='grid items-start gap-2 md:grid-cols-2'>
        {reviews?.map((item) => (
          <ReviewCard
            key={item.id}
            review={item}
            targetAuthor={user}
            showTargetType={true}
            className=''
          />
        ))}
      </div>

and the output looks like this:

So there are gaps between rows one and two in first column which I'd like to remove to nicely displays reviews. What should I change?
EDIT
Masonry layout has poor browser support, any alternatives?
